# MVC best way to parse MySQL XML Table Export

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc

I am looking for a solution that help me to read fast an XML DataBase Export file,
what looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<database name="backup_db">
    <table name="users">
        <column name="username">user1</column>
        <column name="password">pass1</column>
        <column name="email">email1</column>
        <column name="regdate">2015-01-22 23:31:59</column>
        <column name="lastlogin">2016-12-11 01:56:24</column>
        <column name="banned">0</column>
    </table>
    <table name="users">
    ...
    </table>
    ...
    200000 table rows
</database>
```

I make an solution that enumerate all the element and store the column Value, but have a long execution.

```
        var xd = new XmlDocument();
        string path = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/users.xml");
        var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
        xd.Load(fs);

        var list = xd.GetElementsByTagName("table");
        for (var i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
           ...
        }
        fs.Close()
```

Whot to make that work faster ?

Answer (score 0):

Try following.  It only adds data as string and will only work if the columns are always in the same order (no skipped columns)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);
            if (reader.Name != "database")
            {
                reader.ReadToFollowing("database");
            }
            reader.MoveToFirstAttribute();
            string databaseName = reader.Value;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet(databaseName);
            DataTable dt = null;
            while (!reader.EOF)
            {
                if (reader.Name != "table")
                {
                    reader.ReadToFollowing("table");
                }
                if (!reader.EOF)
                {
                    XElement table = (XElement)XElement.ReadFrom(reader);
                    string tableName = (string)table.Attribute("name");
                    if (!ds.Tables.Contains(tableName))
                    {
                        dt = new DataTable(tableName);
                        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
                        dt.Columns.AddRange(table.Elements("column").Select(x => new DataColumn((string)x.Attribute("name"))).ToArray());
                    }
                    DataRow newRow = ds.Tables[tableName].Rows.Add();
                    newRow.ItemArray = table.Elements("column").Select(x => (string)x).ToArray();
                }
            }

        }
    }

}
```